# enable_if with copy/move assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, assignment-operator

I have a class in which I want to enable the copy/move assignment operators only if a type parameter to the class is nothrow copy/move constructible respectively. So I tries this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Foobar {

    Foobar(T value) : x(value) {}
    Foobar(const Foobar &other) : x(other.x) {}
    Foobar(Foobar &&other) : x(std::move(other.x)) {}

    template<bool Condition = std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value,
             typename = typename std::enable_if<Condition>::type>
    Foobar &operator=(const Foobar &rhs) {
        x = rhs.x;
        return *this;
    }

    template<bool Condition = std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value,
             typename = typename std::enable_if<Condition>::type>
    Foobar &operator=(Foobar &&rhs) {
        x = std::move(rhs.x);
        return *this;
    }

    T x;
};

int main() {
    Foobar<int> foo(10);
    Foobar<int> bar(20);

    foo = bar;
    foo.operator=(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, Clang gives me the following error:

```
enable_if_test.cpp:31:9: error: object of type 'Foobar<int>' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly
      deleted
    foo = bar;
        ^
enable_if_test.cpp:8:5: note: copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted because 'Foobar<int>' has a user-declared move
      constructor
    Foobar(Foobar &&other) : x(std::move(other.x)) {}
    ^
enable_if_test.cpp:32:9: error: call to deleted member function 'operator='
    foo.operator=(bar);
    ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
enable_if_test.cpp:4:8: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) has been implicitly deleted
struct Foobar {
       ^
enable_if_test.cpp:12:13: note: candidate function [with Condition = true, $1 = void]
    Foobar &operator=(const Foobar &rhs) {
            ^
enable_if_test.cpp:19:13: note: candidate function [with Condition = true, $1 = void] not viable: no known conversion from
      'Foobar<int>' to 'Foobar<int> &&' for 1st argument
    Foobar &operator=(Foobar &&rhs) {
            ^
2 errors generated.
```

Now, I included the explicit call to the assignment operator to showcase the weirdness of the error. It just says that my template is a candidate function and gives no reason for why it is not chosen.

My guess here is that since I defined a move constructor, the compiler implicitly deleted the copy assignment operator. Since it is implicitly deleted, it doesn't even want to instantiate any template. Why it behaves like this I do not know, however.

How can I achieve this behavior?

(Note: The actual code has legitimate reasons to define each of the members, I'm aware that it is useless here.)

Comment: T is not in the immediate context of the assignment operator, so SFINAE cannot occur. If you add a dummy template parameter defaulted to T, then substitute T for with that parameter for the rest of your template arguments, it should work.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I can't quite grok your argument. As far as I can tell, the problem in the OP is that function templates are not considered as special member functions (with the exception of the default ctor).

Comment: *"it doesn't even want to instantiate any template"* For all I know, you'll end up with a deleted `operator=(Foo const&)` and a function template specialization `operator=<true, void>(Foo const&)`. And as a last resort, non-template functions are preferred over function template specializations - this selects the deleted operator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best and only way to do this is via the rule of zero -- use the compiler-provided assignment operators and constructors, which copy or move each of the members.  If the member `T x` cannot be copy (move) assigned, then the copy (move) assignment operator for your class will default to deleted.

The reason that SFINAE cannot be used to disable copy and/or move assignment operators is that SFINAE requires template context, but copy and move assignment operators are non-template member functions.

> A user-declared copy  assignment `operator X::operator=` is a non-static **non-template** member function of `class X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.

Since your template versions don't count as user-declared copy (move) assignment operators, they won't inhibit generation of the default ones, and because non-templates are preferred, the default ones will be preferred over your template definitions (when the argument is a `const Foobar&`, otherwise the template is a better match, but disabling the template still won't disable the auto-generated one).

If you need some special logic in addition to the call to the member's copy (move) assignment operator, implement it in a subobject (base or member are both feasible).

---

You can perhaps accomplish your goal by selecting from specializations of a class template which you use as a base class, passing the appropriate type traits as you inherit:

```
template<bool allow_copy_assign, bool allow_move_assign>
struct AssignmentEnabler;

template<typename T>
struct Foobar : AssignmentEnabler<std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value, 
                                  std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value>
{
};
```

The derived type will use the rule of zero to default to having copy and move assignment if and only if the selected `AssignmentEnabler` base class does.  You must specialize `AssignmentEnabler` for each of the four combinations (neither copy nor move, copy without move, move without copy, both).

Complete conversion of the code in your question:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<bool enable>
struct CopyAssignmentEnabler {};

template<>
struct CopyAssignmentEnabler<false>
{
    CopyAssignmentEnabler() = default;
    CopyAssignmentEnabler(const CopyAssignmentEnabler&) = default;
    CopyAssignmentEnabler(CopyAssignmentEnabler&&) = default;
    CopyAssignmentEnabler& operator=(const CopyAssignmentEnabler&) = delete;
    CopyAssignmentEnabler& operator=(CopyAssignmentEnabler&&) = default;
};

template<bool enable>
struct MoveAssignmentEnabler {};

template<>
struct MoveAssignmentEnabler<false>
{
    MoveAssignmentEnabler() = default;
    MoveAssignmentEnabler(const MoveAssignmentEnabler&) = default;
    MoveAssignmentEnabler(MoveAssignmentEnabler&&) = default;
    MoveAssignmentEnabler& operator=(const MoveAssignmentEnabler&) = default;
    MoveAssignmentEnabler& operator=(MoveAssignmentEnabler&&) = delete;
};

template<typename T>
struct Foobar : CopyAssignmentEnabler<std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value>,
                MoveAssignmentEnabler<std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value>
{
    Foobar(T value) : x(value) {}

    T x;
};

int main() {
    Foobar<int> foo(10);
    Foobar<int> bar(20);

    foo = bar;
    foo.operator=(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Some will probably find this useful as well: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.se/2012/10/copying-constructors-in-c11.html?m=1