# How do I remove a special constructor from overload resolution?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, overload-resolution

I'm creating an implementation of C++17's `std::optional<class T>` in C++14. The specification states that the move constructor should be excluded from overload resolution if `T` is not move-constructible, and made trivial if `T` is trivially move-constructible. I'm stuck on getting the former.

Here's a code sample of what I have so far:

```
    template<class T, bool = is_trivially_move_constructible_v<T>>
    class optional_move_construct : public optional_copy_construct<T> {
    public:
      optional_move_construct(optional_move_construct&& rhs) :
        optional_base<T>() {
        if (rhs.m_full) {
          _impl_construct(std::move(rhs.m_value));
        }
      }
    };
```

*`optional_copy_construct<T>` is part of the inheritance chain I'm using, so I won't worry about it.*

There are two ways I can "remove" the move constructor, neither of which works for this scenario.

**Option 1:** Delete the move constructor. This won't work because deleted functions are included in overload resolution.
**Option 2:** Use SFINAE to exclude the move constructor from overload resolution. This won't work either, because SFINAE requires a template function to work, and that would be lower-priority than the default move constructor.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How about making all the other move constructors also depend on a template, then disable them except for their expected type

Comment: I think deleting the move constructor is fine.

Comment: Have you looked at [`boost::optional`]( https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A move constructor has one `T&&` argument, and *possibly additional arguments provided those have default values*. That means you can add `std::enable_if_t<Condition, int> = 0` as an additional argument to your move constructor.

The compiler won't create a one-argument `optional::optional(T&&)` move constructor when you have that two-argument move constructor.

Comment: But wouldn't the deleted constructor still participate in overload resolution?

Comment: @VainMan: No, if it's deleted, it's not part of the overload set.

Comment: Do you mean to not declare it or to declare it as `= delete;`? IIRC, the latter will participate in overload resolution and will be the best match.

Comment: I was wrong. It's ambiguous. https://godbolt.org/z/MExM7Pq4h

Comment: I'm not entirely certain about the SFINAE bit though. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29688252/15416