# With std::optional, what does it mean to "remove the move constructor from overload resolution"?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, option-type

I'm creating an implementation of `std::optional` in C++14. However, I'm slightly confused with how the move constructor is specified. Here's what I'm referring to (emphasis mine):

> The expression inside `noexcept` is equivalent to `is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>`.
> **This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless `is_move_constructible_v<T>` is `true`**. If `is_trivially_move_constructible_v<T>` is `true`, this constructor shall be a constexpr
> constructor.

What does it mean to remove the move constructor from overload resolution? Deletion and SFINAE don't seem to work for this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, SFINAE does not work for constructors, use [base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29688252/7691729) forcing the compiler to do the right thing.

It means it is not defined and the class cannot be move constructed. More interesting question is why is it needed?

I am not 100% sure I have the right answer to that.

**TL;DR** Returning `std::optional<NonMoveable>` generates compiler errors if the move constructor of `optional` is present. On the other hand, returning `NonMoveable` directly fallbacks to copy constructor.

First, the constraint does not break anything. The constructor cannot be implemented if `T` cannot be move constructed.

Second, all methods of `std::optional` are very tricky due to `std::optional<std::optional<T>>` issue which could easily lead to ambiguous calls if proper constraints are not taken, `optional(U&& value)` is really susceptible to this.

The main reason is, I believe, because we want `optional<T>` to act as `T` whenever possible and there is one edge case, that I am aware of, when the existence of `std::optional`'s move constructor for non-moveable `T` leads to unnecessary compiler errors. Coincidentally, it is the case of returning `std::optional` by value from functions, something I do very often.

For a variable `x` of type `T`, `return x` in a function `T foo()` calls move constructor if it accessible, copy if not.

Take these simple definitions:

```
#include <utility>
struct CopyOnly {
    CopyOnly() = default;
    CopyOnly(const CopyOnly &) = default;
    CopyOnly(CopyOnly &&) = delete;

    CopyOnly &operator=(const CopyOnly &) = default;
    CopyOnly &operator=(CopyOnly &&) = delete;
    ~CopyOnly() = default;
};

template <typename T> struct Opt {
    Opt() = default;
    Opt(const Opt &other) : m_value(other.m_value) {}
    Opt(Opt &&other) : m_value(std::move(other.m_value)) {
        // Ordinary move ctor.
        // Same as =default, just writing for clarity.
    }
    // Ignore how `T` is actually stored to be "optional".
    T m_value;
};
```

and this example

```
template <typename T> T foo(const T &t) {
    auto x = t;
    return x;
}

int main() {

    Opt<int> opt_int;
    CopyOnly copy;
    Opt<CopyOnly> opt_copy;
    
    foo(opt_int);//#1
    foo(copy);//#2
    foo(opt_copy);//#3
}
```

`return x`:

1. Calls move constructor because `opt_int` can be moved.
2. Calls copy constructor as a fallback because it cannot be moved.
3. Compiler error because `Opt<CopyOnly>` has accessible move constructor so it is chosen, but its instantiation leads to an error due `m_value(std::move(other.m_value))` trying to explicitly calls deleted move ctor.

If one disables the move constructor, copy constructor is chosen and the code is identical to #2.

Answer (score 5):

Use inheritance. Define a base class template and specialize it for different `T` constructability characteristics, marking the move-constructor `delete` as needed.

```
template<bool>
struct enable_move {};

template<>
struct enable_move<true> {
    constexpr enable_move() noexcept = default;
    constexpr enable_move(enable_move&&) noexcept = default;
};

template<>
struct enable_move<false> {
    constexpr enable_move() noexcept = default;
    constexpr enable_move(enable_move&&) noexcept = delete;
};

template<typename T>
struct optional : private enable_move<is_move_constructible<T>::value> {
    // . . .
};
```

The complexity comes when combining this with other special members with similar requirements, like the copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators.

For this reason e.g. in libstdc++, `optional` [derives](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional;h=09e7a7efca7c2378af079350642ad807fcf0e6a2;hb=b4e7013794972ddfcaf042a775b06c94d20ba96b#l655) from `_Enable_copy_move` (see [1](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/enable_special_members.h;h=3c12cfcf8540af83bac5f796c67e46815e5f8570;hb=b4e7013794972ddfcaf042a775b06c94d20ba96b#l76), [2](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/enable_special_members.h;h=3c12cfcf8540af83bac5f796c67e46815e5f8570;hb=b4e7013794972ddfcaf042a775b06c94d20ba96b#l129)), which takes care of all 4 special members at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

It means it doesn't exist in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).  In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you can do this with requires clauses.

You can get fancy with default and inherited bases etc; if you inherit from a class without a move ctor, you don't have one.  Things that don't exist don't participate in overload resolution.

Comment: What does the *requires clauses* in this text mean? Isn't concepts a feature of c++20?

Comment: `optional` exists in C++17, so clearly it can be done in C++17. And since 17 isn't *that* different from 14 in this regard, I suspect it can be done in C++14 too.

Comment: @nicol sure?  Requires is just one solution.  It can just not exist.